# Styling HTML / CSS / javascript player - phantom padding?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't for the life of me seem to figure out why I can't move the song labels in this player featured in the "samples" tab in the middle of the page up so they look more slimmer and balanced. I need someone that is more familar with css to figure out what is causing the space between the top and the text. I'm sure it's an extremely easy fix.

http://www.remedyaudio.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your `<img>` a `style="float:left"` it will remove the top height.

The `float:left` will align the image to the left, allowing the `<span>` to align from the image top, instead of the bottom..

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. I spent hours trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

## Pure CSS

```
#nice2Tab ul li img
{
    float:left;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$('#nice2Tab ul li img').each(function (){

  $(this).css('float','left');

});
```